# @RequestBody not working with @JsonProperty

Tags: json, spring-boot, kotlin, jackson

I'm building an API using `Spring Boot 2.2.2` and `Kotlin 1.3.61`.
I've done it before and don't remember facing this issue.

Basically I have the following DTO:

```
class RequestDTO {
    @JsonProperty(value = "phone_number")
    var phoneNumber: String = ""
}
```

And I want to use it as a parameter for a POST Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/test")
fun test(@RequestBody body: RequestDTO): Object {
    return service.doStuff(body)
}
```

I'm requesting it with

```
{
    "phone_number": "12345"
}
```

My `RequestDTO` does not have the `phoneNumber` property defined (its empty as the default value). If I pass `phoneNumber` in the request, then it deserializes fine.

Also a really strange part is that the following code works fine:

```
val om = ObjectMapper()
val rqDto = RequestDTO()
rqDto.phoneNumber = "12345"

val rqStr = om.writeValueAsString(rqDto) // { "phone_number": "12345" }

val rqDto2 = om.readValue(rqStr, RequestDTO::class.java) // [phoneNumber = "12345"]
```

So the problem seems to be something about `@RequestBody` and `@JsonProperty` together...? Am I missing some configuration?

I have also tried using `@get:JsonProperty()` and `@set:JsonProperty()` without success.

Thanks

Comment: "phone_numer" from the request is a typo, right?

Comment: @amseager yes it was, in the question only. Fixed it, thanks.

Comment: Strangely enough I just started a project from 0 with SPring Initializr and it seems to work fine.... Will dig around to find out if any other dependency in my project is maybe conflicting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, turns out it was a simple problem.
The project has a dependency for that has a dependency for `org.codehaus.jackson` and I was using `org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty` instead of `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty`. Changing it worked. -_-